# Can ISPs fake the results of internet speed test?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, cache, isp

We moved to a new one he claimed to give us 15mb/s to 30mb/s and 30mb/s upload speed.

If you go to any speed testing site, like fast.com or speedtest.net or any other, you see that it shows 30mb/s and so on, so the numbers you see on screen back his claims. Ping is 15, so not a factor.

But if you download a big real file or app, you see that it gets downloaded at 200kb/s and the internet in the house slows down significantly.

How is this possible? I understand that he can cache Youtube and Netflix, but what I don't understand is how does cache has to do with the results from speed testing sites?

Comment: If the Internet slows down while a large download is running not at full speed of your connection the router may be too weak (CPU power) or it does not prioritize TCP status packets like ACK.

Comment: Most ISPs advertise about IP data transfer rate, which is closer to what the end-user / customer, aka you, is going to experience in real-life conditions. Some others, though, still advertise the ATM (Asynchronous Transfer Mode) data transfer rates, because they're usually more flattering. The key is that, in ATM measurement, one link (down vs up) is measured separately, thus reserving the whole bandwidth for one operation at a time, be it download or upload. In real-life conditions, you'll want duplex connectivity, not alternate, hence the more flattering results in ATM mode vs IP mode.

Comment: @Didier - That's going to be very dependant on where in the world you live. In the UK [& I think now in all EU] they can only sell you what you should reasonably expect from their service, not some "up to *nn*mbps" that in reality no-one more than 800m from the exchange ever actually gets. The entire "up to" business was outlawed a few years ago.

Comment: It sure should have been, but I don't know exactly where the OP lives, so it could be that his ISP advertised data transfer rates that only exist in perfect conditions. Could also be that someone piggy-backed his/her WiFi...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely suspected that ISP's give priority to speed tests. There's not a great deal you can do about this except to try testing to a datacentre a long way from you, which *may* give a slightly different picture.

There are a huge number of factors that can make a real-world file transfer be slow, though. The far site's delivery capability, how busy it is between you & them, whether a CDN has it cached locally or you're having to fetch from half-way round the world… & that's before we get to your own local network - with bufferbloat, congested or noisy wifi etc etc.

To avoid the mainstream prioritised tests, I always give DSL Reports a try. I'n sure ISPs will prioritise them too, but they have additional tools you can employ if it detects some other factor in play.

Try https://www.dslreports.com/speedtest & let us know how you get on.
Also read their "Why is this the best speed test" section at the end.

Comment: 2mBits download, 4mbBits upload, this test is the correct one it seems

Comment: You may want to test your connection speed using iperf. The best would be using private iperf server running in a datacenter, although public iperf servers may do the trick as well.

Comment: I'm with ATT Uverse and when I go to https://www.dslreports.com/speedtest first of all I have to navigate around all the FAKE speed test Ads..  BOOO!!!!   Then click on cable or fiber or anything, your site gives me an error I can't reach all 6 locations.   so NO, not your tests.

Comment: @Chizl - use an ad blocker. I'm afraid after that we can't be held responsible for what your ISP will or will not allow you to connect to.

Comment: "There's not a great deal you can do about this except to try testing to a datacentre a long way from you, which may give a slightly different picture."


Uhh, no. That is testing way more than your connection. It is testing every link between your local connection and that server 6000 miles away. To test throughput, you should be testing _just_ outside your ISPs network.

Comment: @greg5green - I used to be support for an online gaming structure. We used to give out direct links to servers in specific locations & get the user's results back to establish where their bottleneck was. It didn't fix anything in itself, of course, but it gave an understanding of a broader situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in my opinion.  I checked my AT&T wireless speed using their official Internet Speed Test page. I found that when connected to certain ATT sites the signal was boosted to my cellphone.  For example, when connected to non-AT&T sites my everyday signal strength was in the -107 to -120 dBm range (Terrible).  When connected to AT&T speed check site or when setting up my voicemail for the first time, my signal strength was in the -88 to -95 dBm range (Good) and then immediately back to previous levels upon disconnecting. I'd be surprised if other carriers don't do the same thing.

Comment: Your WiFi and cellular signal strength literally has ZERO to do with what server you are trying to connect to.